# Android String Listview

Tags: android, string, listview

Hi I came across the listview example referencing a string array defined by an external class. I was wanting to inquire how would one change it to when the items in the list are clicked it would bring up a new page with info on it.

Thank you in advance sorry for the noob question I'm new at android/Java.

```
strings.xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
            <string name="hello">Hello World, HelloListView!</string>
            <string name="app_name">HelloListView</string>
        <string-array name="countries_array">
                <item>Bahrain</item>
                <item>Bangladesh</item>
                <item>Barbados</item>
                <item>Belarus</item>
                <item>Belgium</item>
                <item>Belize</item>
                <item>Benin</item>
            </string-array>
        </resources>




            package com.hope;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.app.ListActivity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            import android.widget.TextView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
                /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries));

                    ListView lv = getListView();
                    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                          int position, long id) {
                        //When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                    });
                  }
            }
        list_item.xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </TextView>
```

Comment: when you say 'new page' what do you mean? A dialog? a new activity? something else? If you mean a new activity @Reno has got you on the right path. You'd probably want a switch(position) and for each of the rows you'd have a case row_ID: specify the correct activity for this item and start it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an onClick Listener like this. [Read about adapters first](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html)

```
 OnItemClickListener itemListener = new OnItemClickListener() {  
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
          int position, long rowid) {
            Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, YourNewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);      
        }
    };
```